# Orthogonal Vector Space with Identity Matrix and Orthogonal Projection

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-equations, projective-space, orthogonal-matrices

I'm doing some homework and I'm having some trouble trying to prove something about orthogonal vector spaces. Given a vector space $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ and $P$ an orthogonal projection on $S$ it asks me to prove that $(\mathbb{I} - P)x \in S^\perp \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^m$. This is what I did:

First I took $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and defined $s=Px$ and $v=(\mathbb{I} - P)y$. Because $P$ is an orthogonal projection on $S$ I know that $s \in S$. So, I want to see that the inner product of $s$ and $v$ is zero for any $x$ and $y$ to prove that $v \in S^\perp$. So:

$$
s^\dagger v = (Px)^\dagger (\mathbb{I} - P)y \\
= x^\dagger P^\dagger y - x^\dagger P^\dagger
 P y \\
= x^\dagger P^\dagger y - x^\dagger y
$$

I got this far. I tried to look for some identity that proves this but I couldn't find any. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why does $x^* P^* P y = x^* y$?

Comment: Because $P$ is an orthogonal matrix, so by definition $PP^\dagger = \mathbb{I}$.

Comment: I think you and the answerer may be confusing orthogonal matrices and orthogonal projections. An orthogonal projection is not a projection that is an orthogonal matrix it is instead idempotent and self-adjoint, so $P^* P = P^2 = P \neq \mathbb{I}$ unless $S = \mathbb{R^m} $

Comment: You're right, I was mislead by the name... I will remove the answer as a correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Since $P$ is orthogonal, we have $P^T = P$ by definition. Take $x$ in $\mathbb R^n$ and $y$ in $S$. Since $P$ is a projection on $S$, $S$ is the image of $P$ so we have $y = Py$ (because $P^2 = P$). Now

$$
\langle x - Px, y \rangle
= \langle x, y \rangle - \langle Px, y \rangle
= x^Ty - x^T \underbrace{P^T}_{=P} y
= x^Ty - x^T(P y) = x^Ty - x^Ty = 0.
$$

Hence the result.

Comment: Thank you my dude, the problem was that I wasn't using the property that if $s \in S$ then $P s = s$.

Comment: EDIT: This answer is incorrect since we thought an orthogonal projection is an orthogonal matrix (which is NOT). I removed the checkmark from the answer. If somebody con help me with this I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: Oh yes sorry I went a little fast there, sorry about that! I edited my answer, the proof relies on the fact that an orthogonal projection matrix is symetric (i.e. it satisfies $P^T = P$) so you can put $P$ on the other side of the inner product.

Answer (score 0):

As $P$ is an orthogonal projection we know P is self adjoint, i.e. $\langle P x, y \rangle = \langle x, P y \rangle$. Taking $x\in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $y \in S$ we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle (I-P) x, y \rangle &= \langle x, y \rangle  -  \langle P x,  y \rangle \\
&=  \langle x, y \rangle -  \langle x, P y \rangle \\
&=  \langle x, y \rangle -  \langle x,  y \rangle \\
&=0
\end{aligned} 
$$
where on the penultimate line we used the fact that $P y = y$.